# Icons available for ExtJS's Panel's "tool" buttons

Tags: extjs4

How can I set icon used in my Panel's "Title Bar"? Maybe I need to add an image myself, but if so I suppose I need to define or configure that somewhere?

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    title: 'Projects',
    width: 200,
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('projects'),
    tools: [
        {
            type: 'add', // this doesn't appear to work, probably I need to use a valid class
            tooltip: 'Add project',
            handler: function() {
                console.log('TODO: Add project');
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
},
```

Comment: Hmm, have you tried:

items:[{
 icon : ///Some url

}]
?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a set of 25 icons that can be specified by using the type config.
check http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type

To get add symbol use

```
tools:[{
    type:'plus',
    tooltip: 'Add project',
    // hidden:true,
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
        // Add logic
    }
}]
```

the specified **type:'add'** is not in the list

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add your own tool type and be able to assign it an image of your own, you can do the following:

Add a css class in your css file:

```
.x-tool-mytool { background-image: url(path_to_your_image_file) !important; }
```

Then in your tools, simply use 'mytool' as the type:

```
            {
                type:'mytool',
                tooltip: 'This is my tool',
                handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
                    // my tool logic
                }
            }
```

Make sure that you use the same name in tool's type as you used for the css class suffix.

Answer (score 4):

according to the ExtJS documentation, these predefined types are available:

```
collapse, expand, maximize, minimize, resize, restore, move, close 

minus, plus, prev, next, pin, unpin, search, toggle, refresh

save, print, gear, help

right, left, up, down
```

one can enter whatever type one wants:

```
{type: 'YOURTYPE'}
```

while providing a **15px** icon - or preferably icon sprites

(the background-position certainly not applies for single icons, but icon sprites):

```
.x-tool-img.x-tool-YOURTYPE{
   background: url('../images/custom_tool_sprites.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

sources: [Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type), [codefx.biz](http://www.codefx.biz/2014/12/custom-icon-sets-extjs-tool-types).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "set buttons used in my Panel's Title Bar", not "set icon". You can use `buttons` config of Panel, not `tools`:

```
buttons: [{ 
   text: 'Add',
   tooltip: 'Add project',
   handler: function() {
      console.log('TODO: Add project');
   }
}]
```

You can use other configurations like `bbar` (bottom bar), `fbar` (footer), `tbar` (top), `lbar` (left), `rbar` (right) for position the toolbar. One small notice is the config objects in `buttons` have the default `xtype` as `button`, so you don't need to explicitly specify them.